# Implement own unique Python Mock module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, class, mocking

I work on an own unique Python Mock module. It will be integrated a big and complex system. This Mock module contains many features but these are not working due to logical issue so I will show one of them as a representative example.

The following part of current implementation works as a context manager and it should change the reference of original object to reference of mocked object.

**Mock module file:**

```
class MockContextManager(object):
    def __init__(self, original, mocked=None):
        self.original = original
        self.mocked = mocked
    def __enter__(self):
        # We have to save the original reference of the object and assign
        # the reference of the mocked object to original.
        exec("self.local_original = {}".format(self.original))
        exec("{} = {}".format(self.original, self.mocked))
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # Assign back to the original reference of the object.
        exec("{} = self.local_original".format(self.original))
        if exc_type is not None:
            traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
```

**Usage file:**

```
from reference_mock import MockContextManager
from other_test_file import FunctionClass

def functionless_dummy_function(*args, **kwargs):
    return None

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.function_class_instance = FunctionClass()

    def test_mock_context_manager(self):

        with MockContextManager(
            original="self.function_class_instance.show_info",
            mocked="functionless_dummy_function",
        ):
            # The "functionless_dummy_function" function should be called instead of "show_info" method.
            self.function_class_instance.show_info()
```

**Getting error:**

```
AttributeError: 'MockContextManager' object has no attribute 'function_class_instance'
```

Okay, I understand the problem but I have to use `self` to identify my instance variable.

If I want to redirect a global variable, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'my_global_veriable' is not defined
```

I have tried to pass the `self` as parameter and create the variable as a string in the `exec` but it didn't work. Furthermore, I tried to calculate the name of the caller module but I get very similar error in every case.

**NOTE:**

- The built-in Mock module usage is not option.
- If I implement 2 local functions, I can redirect the references correctly.
- I am open to every possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue with the `__code__` magic method. You can get with `__code__`: code object containing compiled function bytecode. Actually my context manager is changing the compiled code in the getting methods/functions.

**Code:**

```
class MockContextManager(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        original: Any,
        mocked: Any = None,
    ):
        self.original = original
        self.mocked = mocked

    def __enter__(self):

        # We have to save the original reference of the object and assign
        # the reference of the mocked object to original.
        self.prev = getattr(self.original, "__code__")
        self.original.__code__ = getattr(self.mocked, "__code__")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # Set back the original reference of the getting object.
        self.original.__code__ = self.prev
        if exc_type is not None:
            traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
```

**Usage:**

```
from my_module import my_function  # "my_function" returns 10  

def my_mocked_function():
    return 5

print(my_function)
with MockContextManager(original=my_function, mocked=my_mocked_function):
    print(my_function)
print(my_function)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
10
5
10
```